# Trello API: Getting invalid token on all calls

Tags: api, oauth, token, trello

I have a weird situation, which I hope you can help with.

I am trying to setup a simple Trello application. What I do are the following:

1. I go to https://trello.com/app-key and get my KEY
2. I go to https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&name=SinglePurposeToken&key=MYKEY for a permanent server to server key
3. I authorize
4. I get a token

Now I'm ready, but then when I want to make a call such as:

https://api.trello.com/1/boards/BOARDID/actions/?limit=2&key=MYKEY&token=MYTOKEN

I get "invalid token".

Reason I post here on StackOverflow, and not Trello support, is because I assume there is something basic I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wrong about step 2).

I should use this link instead:

https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&scope=read,write&response_type=token&name=APPNAME&key=KEY

This gave the working token. All is well!

Comment: CodeScene users: this is the way that you can integrate CodeScene to Trello.